# Array returned by querying Google datastore is not ordered correctly

Tags: php

I an using PHP to query Google cloud datastore records.
This is my PHP code:

```
$datastore = new DatastoreClient(['projectId' => $projectId, 'namespaceId' => 'ssd']);
function getList(DatastoreClient $datastore){
    $cursor=null;
    $query = $datastore->query()
        ->kind('keypad_research')
              ->start($cursor);

  $results = $datastore->runQuery($query);
    $entries = [];

    foreach ($results as $entity) {
        $entry = $entity->get();
        $entry['id'] = $entity->key()->pathEndIdentifier();
        $entries[] = $entry;
    }
    return [
        'entries' => $entries,
    ];
}
```

The result returned look like this:

```
Array
(
    [entries] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [phone6] => 1827533132
                    [gender] => Male
                    [phone2] => 1827533132
                    [concept3] => 2.84
                    [concept6] => 0
                    [race] => White
                    [phone4] => 1827533132
                    [age] => 26-35
                    [concept2] => 2.06
                    [concept5] => 3.56
                    [phone3] => 1827533132
                    [phone1] => 1827533132
                    [concept1] => 2.53
                    [phone5] => 1827533132
                    [concept4] => 12.8100
                    [id] => 4795887050031104
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [phone3] => 1234567890
                    [phone1] => 1234567890
                    [concept1] => 4.16
                    [phone5] => 1234567890
                    [concept4] => 2.7300
                    [phone6] => 0
                    [gender] => Male
                    [phone2] => 1234567890
                    [concept3] => 2.71
                    [concept6] => 0
                    [race] => Black
                    [phone4] => 1234567890
                    [age] => 46-65
                    [concept2] => 3.6
                    [concept5] => 3.36
                    [id] => 4796717991985152
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [race] => White
                    [phone4] => -442751970
                    [age] => 18-25
                    [concept2] => 54.84
                    [concept5] => 3.17
                    [phone3] => -442751970
                    [phone1] => -442751970
                    [concept1] => 2.62
                    [phone5] => -442751970
                    [concept4] => 2.3700
                    [phone6] => -442751970
                    [gender] => Male
                    [phone2] => -442751970
                    [concept3] => 3.29
                    [concept6] => 2.58
                    [id] => 4804278879256576
                )
        )
)
```

As you can see, the array items are not ordered in the same way, each array is ordered differently. I was wondering if I should write the code differently so that every array returned has same order of items?

I would like every array item to be like this:

```
[2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4804278879256576
                    [phone1] => -442751970
                    [concept1] => 2.62
                    [phone2] => -442751970
                    [concept2] => 54.84
                    [phone3] => -442751970
                    [concept3] => 3.29
                    [phone4] => -442751970
                    [concept4] => 2.3700
                    [phone5] => -442751970
                    [concept5] => 3.17
                    [phone6] => -442751970
                    [concept6] => 2.58
                    [race] => White
                    [age] => 18-25
                    [gender] => Male
                )
```

Thanks

Comment: Although it's untidy for printing, what difference does it make? you can still access the elements as `$array['entries'][$i]['phone2']` regardless of internal ordering in the array.

Comment: Thats right, I can still access as you mentioned. I was just wondering that if I could make it cleaner.

Comment: You could just use `ksort($entry);` before `$entries[] = $entry;`

Comment: Thanks Nick, that does sort it :) Not in the specific order i want, but now they are all same order.

Comment: You could use `uksort` to sort in the exact order you want, but it would be a pretty complicated sort function...